# How to extract an HTML anchor's href from a file in Bash?

Tags: html, bash

At the page https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html, there is a link to the Android SDK tools for Linux, which I'd like to download by a script. Unfortunately, there is no "easy" link to use to download the latest version, so I'd like to extract the link from the HTML itself.

The link is identified by the id `linux-tools` and is contained on multiple lines:

```
  <a onclick="return onDownload(this)" id="linux-tools" data-modal-toggle="studio_tos"
    href="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip">sdk-tools-linux-38593
```

I'd like to extract that `href` into a variable in a Bash script. The closest I've gotten so far is the following:

```
grep -o -z '<a.[^<]*id="linux-tools"[^<]*</a>' index.html
```

which outputs the above two lines.

How do I get at the actual link using typically-available shell commands?

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, I know. I have a Python script that will be able to do this but my current environment is constrained to using a bash script, not embedding any other languages and not installing additional tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is very close. All that remains to do is extracting the `href` part:

```
grep -zoP '<a[^<]*id="linux-tools"[^<]*href="\K[^"]+' index.html
```

We used PCRE (`-P`) and PCRE's special escape sequence, [the reset match start `\K`](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#resetmatchstart), which causes any previously matched characters not to be included in the final matched sequence (we need only the part between the double quotes).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to first select the range you want to work, for example:

```
sed -n '/id="linux-tools"/,+1 p' index.html
```

That will give you the address from line containing `id="linux-tools"` plus one line.

Now you can use `sed` substitute to extract the `href` just from that range:

```
sed -n '/id="linux-tools"/,+1 s/.*href="\([^"]*\).*$/\1/p' index.html
```